# Working with Asp.Net ListView and Asp.Net Ajax Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, datapager

Hello there, I hope this will be easy for someone to answer. First off I was trying to make a `ListView` bound to a `DataPager` and put in an ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` to make an AJAX-powered pager for the records from my database. I grabbed an `UpdatePanel` and I placed:

1. `SqlDataSource`
2. `ListView` - having `ItemTemplate` including one `ImageButton` and several other ASP.NET controls in it
3. `DataPager`

in the `ContentTemplate`. Assigning the `DataPager` ID to the `AsyncPostbackTrigger` in the `UpdatePanel`'s trigger fields worked perfectly.

I also wanted to perform a full post-back in the `ImageButton` `Click` event. However, because the `ImageButton` is inside the `ListView`,  the `UpdataPanel` causes a partial post-back. I tried adding the ImageButton as an `UpdatePanel` `PostBackTrigger`, but the `UpdatePanel` demands a control ID, and won't accept the `ImageButton` since it is inside the `ListView`.

How do I pass it a control ID for an element inside `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView` and successfully cause a full post back?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ... ></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewForAlbums" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="album">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="albumPhoto" class="albumPhotosStyle" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Bind('albumPhotoPath') %>" AlternateText="<%# Bind('album_id') %>" ToolTip="<%# Bind('albumDetails') %>" onclick="albumPhotos_Click"  />
                    <div class="albumInfoHolder">

                    ...

                    </div>
                </div> <!-- End Album -->
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <p>No Albums Yet. Check Back Soon!</p>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPagerForAlbums" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListViewForAlbums" PageSize="3" >
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True" FirstPageText="&laquo" ShowNextPageButton="False"  ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True" LastPageText="&raquo" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"  ShowNextPageButton="false" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DataPagerForAlbums" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ScriptManager to register the control as a postback control. Do something like this in the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton button = e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1") as ImageButton;
    if (button != null)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(button);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ItemDataBound ListView's event to get ImageButton and register it as a postback control with ScriptManager's RegisterPostBackControl method.

Comment: nvm i did it. Thanks so much SIR :)